# Problem with table rows

Tags: tables, multirow, columns, width

I am facing an issue with the last row of the table here attached. 
[image]

I would like to have the width of the three columns to be equal. How can I do that? Here below the code I am using:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|l|c|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{${k_p}^2 = \frac{{f_{DH}}^2 - {f_{EH}}^2}{{f_{DH}}^2}$}}                                                          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{${k_{em}}^2 = \frac{{f_{EB}}^2 - {f_{EH}}^2}{{f_{EB}}^2}$}}                                                        \\
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$K_{DH} = \frac{\alpha^2}{C_0}\frac{{f_{DH}}^2}{{f_{DH}}^2-{f_{EH}}^2} = \frac{\alpha^2}{C_0}\frac{1}{{k_p}^2}$}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$K_{EB} = \frac{\beta^2}{L_0}\frac{{f_{EB}}^2}{{f_{EB}}^2-{f_{EH}}^2} = \frac{\beta^2}{L_0}\frac{1}{{k_{em}}^2}$}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}                                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$K_{EH} = K_{DH} - \frac{\alpha^2}{C_0}$}}                                                                        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$K_{DB} = K_{EB} - \frac{\beta^2}{L_0}$}}                                                                          \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}                                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$M = \frac{K_{EH}}{{\omega_{EH}}^2}$}}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$C = \frac{M\omega_{DH}}{Q_m}$}}                                 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$Q_m = \frac{f_0}{f_2 - f_1}$}}                                \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                                              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: why is every cell in a multicolumn? and there are no vertical spanning so why use \multirow at all?

Comment: do you want the three in the bottom row equal so the left column twice as wide as the right column for the rest of the table? with the contents shown it would look more balanced if the first two columns were the half width of teh third so the main division was in the centre?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been clear: I meant that I would like only the last row of the table to have equal column width

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tabularx`-based solution that lets you get rid of each and every `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` wrapper. It also strives to create a more open "look" by getting rid of all vertical lines and the majority of horizontal lines.

The widths of both `tabularx` environments is set to `\textwidth`. The first `tabularx` environment contains 2 centered X-type columns, and it's used for the first three rows. The second `tabularx` environment contains 3 centered X-type columns and applies just to the last row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % how to display variable names
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$\displaystyle }X<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CC @{}}
\toprule
k_p^2 = \frac{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2 - {f_{\vn{EH}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2} & 
k_{em}^2 = \frac{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2 - {f_{\vn{EH}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2} \\ 
\addlinespace
K_{\vn{DH}} = 
      \frac{\alpha^2}{C^{}_0}\frac{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2-{f_{\vn{EH}}}^2} = 
      \frac{\alpha^2}{C^{}_0}\frac{1}{{k_p}^2} & 
K_{\vn{EB}} = 
      \frac{\beta^2}{L^{}_0}\frac{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2-{f_{\vn{EH}}}^2} = 
      \frac{\beta^2}{L^{}_0}\frac{1}{{k_{em}}^2}\\ 
\addlinespace
K_{\vn{EH}} = K_{\vn{DH}} - \frac{\alpha^2}{C^{}_0} & 
K_{\vn{DB}} = K_{\vn{EB}} - \frac{\beta^2}{L^{}_0} \\
\addlinespace
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CCC @{}}
M   = \frac{K_{\vn{EH}}}{{\omega_{\vn{EH}}}^2} & 
C   = \frac{M\omega_{\vn{DH}}}{Q_m} & 
Q_m = \frac{f^{}_0}{f_2 - f_1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just for the sake of completeness, here's a second solution which left-aligns the contents of the 2nd and 3rd rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % how to display variable names
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$\displaystyle}X<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash$\displaystyle}X<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CC @{}}
\toprule
k_p^2 = \frac{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2 - {f_{\vn{EH}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2} & 
k_{em}^2 = \frac{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2 - {f_{\vn{EH}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2} \\ 
\addlinespace
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{}}
K_{\vn{DH}} = 
      \frac{\alpha^2}{C^{}_0} \frac{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{DH}}}^2-{f_{\vn{EH}}}^2} = 
      \frac{\alpha^2}{C^{}_0} \frac{1}{{k_p}^2} & 
K_{\vn{EB}} = 
      \frac{\beta^2}{L^{}_0} \frac{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2}{{f_{\vn{EB}}}^2-{f_{\vn{EH}}}^2} = 
      \frac{\beta^2}{L^{}_0} \frac{1}{{k_{em}}^2} \\ 
\addlinespace
K_{\vn{EH}} = K_{\vn{DH}} - \frac{\alpha^2}{C_0} & 
K_{\vn{DB}} = K_{\vn{EB}} - \frac{\beta^2}{L_0} \\
\addlinespace
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CCC @{}}
M   = \frac{K_{\vn{EH}}}{{\omega_{\vn{EH}}}^2} & 
C   = \frac{M\omega_{\vn{DH}}}{Q_m} & 
Q_m = \frac{f^{}_0}{f_2 - f_1} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```